# Rails change background of new.html.erb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

On the index.html.erb page, I am using a custom black background. This custom background, by default, is also used on all other pages including the page for new.html.erb (_form.html.erb), edit.html.erb, etc...

Is there a way to change the background on the other pages (for example a background that is white) on the other pages such as new.html.erb? If so, how can one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for layouts: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Specifically, you could have a `black_background` and a `white_background` layout.  Then you just render your partials with one or the other layout depending on which you want.

Comment: I answered first but it's ok :) You gave more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create a new template for it and use it when you want that background